# Use the native scrolling behavior of the device

Tags: qooxdoo

I have a qooxdoo desktop application which is also used on mobile devices so I would like to use the native scrolling behavior of the app runs on smartphone or tablet. I tried to do this by setting the environment variable qx.mobile.nativescroll to true in the config file of the app but unfortunatly this doesn't have any effect.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the *qx.nativeScrollBars* environment variable to achieve this. This is a build time setting, so you need to place it into your config.json.

```
"common":
{
  "environment" :
  {
     "qx.nativeScrollBars" : true
  }
}
```

Edit:

As documented [in the qooxdoo documentation](http://manual.qooxdoo.org/current/pages/core/environment.html), you can change this setting programatically from within your index.html / URL parameter. In this case you have to omit the config.json modification.